# Adding bold and underline in a Power Apps formula

Tags: powerapps-forms, formula, append-changes

I have a formula (see below) to append comments in Power Apps. It is under "default" in the card. I am struggling to get "User().FullName & " " & Now()" of the formula to be bold and underlined, and still have the comments append. I have been able to get it to underline but then the comments stop appending.

If(Not(IsBlank(RichTextCommands.HtmlText)),User().FullName & " " & Now() & " " & RichTextCommands.HtmlText) & ThisItem.Comments

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you storing these comments in "rich text" multiple lines of text column SharePoint?

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MicrosoftMVP Yes.

Comment: Try this: `If(Not(IsBlank(RichTextCommands.HtmlText)), "<u>" & User().FullName & "</u>" & " " & Now() & " " & RichTextCommands.HtmlText) & ThisItem.Comments` and see if it adds underline to text. Let me know if it works or not.

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MicrosoftMVP.  That did not work.